# How to perform several actions with non-blocking delay?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, delay, nonblocking

I need to put first image on screen, then put the second after 1 second, and then - the last one after one more second. Also, this should be done in non-blocking manner :) How do you perform that in such cases? Was thinking about nesting several UIView animateWithDuration class methods, but I do not need any animations, I just need to put several images on screen in straight manner with a delay after each step.

UPDATE: IMHO it's too heavyweight approach to use NSTimer for this simple problem. I should need to get a reference, schedule 3 different timers (or one with very if'y method) and then to stop somehow. If so, I would like to to it all from within one method. In that case, if I initiate timer with scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval then IMHO I need to stop (invalidate) somewhere else or smth?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to delay while retaining a responsive GUI on Cocoa Touch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232143/how-to-delay-while-retaining-a-responsive-gui-on-cocoa-touch)

Comment: Hm, I just need to perform the 3 actions once, that's it. Using NSTimer needs to get a reference, perform one cycle ant then stop it. Too much for simple task.

Comment: You can also add a method "call" to the message queue after a delay in C using dispatch_after and blocks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `NSObject`'s [`performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:).

Comment: That's what the `withObject:` parameter is for.

Comment: No block-based equivalent besides `dispatch_after`?

Answer (score -1):

use `[NSThread detachNewThread:Selector:toTarget:withObject:]`. You can get the event when the current thread is finished by using `[[NSThread currentThread] isFinished]`. Thats the way you can do all task with a non-blocking manner. For more information see the   [NSThread Class reference here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSThread_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Happy Coding!

Comment: NSThread is not a background thread dear. You can define a selector in which you can use `performSelectorOnMainThread` and call this selector in NSThread. Be clear!

Comment: `+[NSThread detachNewThread:...]` _does_ create a thread which is not the main thread, a.k.a., a "background thread". Why would you create a new thread if all you're going to do on it is call back to the main thread?